# How to read-write json file outside WAR package?

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, jboss

I am writing a `REST API` in `Java EE 1.6` using `JBoss 7` and basic EE frameworks. I compile the WAR package and then deploy it to Jboss standalone folder. *I was creating a database to store the API configuration, but it is so little (and needs to be full loaded with the servlet) that I decided a JSON file is enough.*

I want to read and write JSON code to a file outside the WAR package, but in the same server JBoss resides (could even be in the same directory as WAR file or other predefined directory).

The reason is that I need this file to be read and written by other applications also.

So How can I perform that reading and writing in the Servlet? *I prefer solutions that includes less dependencies as possible, like no container or framework dependencies, except the JSON and IO libraries, if possible.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This file should not be on public path, so clients can't download it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [File() class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_file_class.htm) can do the job by specifying the directory where file is in the first parameter. Then use it's methods to read, write or append data.